# Android loading of large bitmaps

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I'm making an Android app and I need to load an image (bitmap) in a cavas and resize it using the "pinch zoom" gesture. When the image is over a certain size, however, the application crashes (OutOfMemory exception). How do I optimize the loading and manipulation of the image?

To load the image I use:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource (ctx.getResources (), R.drawable.image)
```

To draw it:

```
imgCanvas.drawBitmap (image, posX, posY, null),
```

To change its size:

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap (originalBitmap, neww, NEWH, true);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not trivial.

Based on the current scale of the image and the currently visible part of the image, only load a part of that image at the appropriate resolution:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html

When zoomed-out and you want to show the entire image scaled down, use the methods from this `BitmapRegionDecoder` class that take a `BitmapFactory.Options` parameter and set it `inSampleSize` to a value larger than 1 (preferably a value that is a power of 2):
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize

When zooming in, first zoom in the lower resolution that is already shown (where you used a value of inSampleSize > 1) and lazily load a higher resolution version (where `inSampleSize` is smaller than the previous value you used) using the `BitmapRegionDecoder` and fade in the higher resolution version gradually.

When the user zooms in, keep doing this until your `inSampleSize` is 1.

Comment: I initially load the image in its original size (with inSampleSize = 1). When I make the "zoom in" I have to change inSampleSize with a value> 1 and then crop the image?

Comment: Before the user zooms in, you load your entire image with inSampleSize > 1. Then when the user zooms in, at certain points, you will load the image again, but only part of it and with a inSampleSize that has lower value  (but still more than 1). When the user zooms in over and over again, at some point, your inSampleSize = 1 (and you'll have loaded only the part that is visible).